# module and class with the same name in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Earlier today I had this problem, when I was running

```
sidekiq
```

I was getting the following error:

> ```
> I, [2015-09-04T12:43:33.723243 #15197]  INFO -- : Celluloid 0.17.1.2 is running in BACKPORTED mode. [ http://git.io/vJf3J ]
> Report is not a class
> /home/andreydeineko/employees/app/models/report.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
> ```

but `Report` was AR class/model without any typos.

It occurred the error was due to the fact, that in the project there was previously defined module called `Report`.

Why is this problem with same class and module name occurred?

Is there any Ruby/Rails convention to not name the class and module with same name?

Comment: *"there was previously defined module called Report."* - what does that mean? Are there different processes with both, old and new code?

Comment: Not at the moment of me running sidekiq. I did not know that project had a module called `Report` (and even if I knew I would still name my class `Report` because I did not know it would lead to a problem). And when I defined class `Report`  which had nothing to do with module `Report` sidekiq complained with `Report is not a class`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reuse the same name for a `Class` and a `Module`. Internally, in Ruby modules are represented as class structures therefore they share the same object space.

Moreover, when you define a Module/Class, you can access the name as a constant.

```
class Report
  def foo
    p "report"
  end
end

Report
=> Report

defined? Report
 => "constant"
```

in fact, you can also write

```
Report = Class.new do
  def foo
    p "report"
  end
end

report = Report.new
report.foo
```

Long story short, if you define `Report` as `Class`, you cannot create a `Module` with the same name.

Comment: A constant can - of course - only reference a single object, but technically you can create multiple classes / modules with the same [`name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-name), that's just an attribute.

Comment: So I suppose this 
**"Internally, in Ruby modules are represented as class structures therefore they share the same object space."** is the main point, right? But what order does Rails use while calling a constant? by my example Rails recognized `Report` constant referring to a module (and didn't care about class 'Report') - do modules always go first in this chain?

Comment: It simply depends on which file was loaded first.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any Ruby/Rails convention to not name the class and module with same name?

The `class` keyword does two things - it either create a new class and assigns it to the given constant or it reopens an existing class based on the given constant. (same for `module`)

In the latter case, it will also raise an error if the constant is not the expected class. It does not matter whether it is a module or another object:

```
Report = 123

class Report
end
#=> TypeError: Report is not a class
```

Comment: this does not answer my question, since I had a class `Report` in my application, and it would still raise the error.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko a `TypeError` indicates that the `Report` constant is already defined and that it is not a class, just like in my example.

Comment: but in console manipulating both module and class works. What order does Rails use while calling a constant? modules first?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko *"both module and class works"* - how do you "switch" between them in console?

Comment: the class and the module defined under different namespaces

Comment: I think I should now read about constants lookup in Ruby (probably not Rails' issue)

Comment: Rails loading mechanism is quite complex - it attempts to load (and in development *re*load) the files as needed. And sometimes it doesn't load a particular file if its corresponding constant is already defined. For example, if there is a top level constant `Report` and you are referring to `Report` from within a namespace, Rails might not load the namespaced file because there already is a `Report` constant. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a general answer, it all depends on your setup / structure.