# Nesting class in module vs using module as part of class name

Tags: ruby, module, namespaces

Similar to [module and class with the same name in Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396212), but I'm trying to understand why putting it all on one line works but using separate lines does not.

Working with inviting new users to an account. My `user` model has the minimum validation, and I use subclasses with additional behavior. This is similar to service objects, but subclasses are cleaner than services most of the time because they are all kept in the `/app/models` folder and is easier to maintain.

I have `app/models/user/as_invitation.rb`. When it looks like the following, it works fine:

```
class ::User::AsInvitation < ::User
  # ...
end
```

But when I have this, it does not work: "User is not a module".

```
module User
  class AsInvitation < ::User
    # ...
  end
end
```

My suspicion is that Ruby uses the same namespace for modules/classes, and since I already have a `User` class (model), it collides with the `User` module (module vs model).

I can use the `::User::AsInvitation` format and it works, but it bugs me when magic happens. As another solution, I can use the module name `Users` plural, but it makes more sense to me to use singular `User` as the namespace.

I'm trying to understand a bit under-the-hood of how Ruby/Rails implement this as well as determine if I go ahead and use `::User::AsInvitation` on one line, whether I am going to find myself down a river without a paddle.

Comment: There is no namespace for modules or classes. A class or module is just an object like any other object.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I guess I'm wondering why `::User::AsInivation` works fine, but when I nest them on separate lines it does not work?

Comment: `module User` opens up the module referenced by the constant `User` (looking it up in the current scope) if `User` is defined, creates the constant `User` with an empty module first if it isn't defined. In your case, the constant `User` is defined, but Ruby fails when trying to open up the module, because `User` doesn't reference a module, it references a class. `::User::AsInvitation` dereferences the constant `User` (in the scope of `Object`), then dereferences the constant `AsInvitation` nested within the module or class referenced by `User`.

Comment: The point is: there is nothing special at all about classes or modules. If you had a `String` assigned to `User` and tried to do `Fixnum` operations with it, you would also get an error. In this case, you have a `Class` assigned to `User` but you are using `Module` operations on it. In the first case, you do not care whether it is a class or module, you only dereference a nested constant, and both modules and classes can contain constants.

Comment: @JörgWMittag True, there is no namespace for modules or classes, but there *are* namespaces for *constants* used by convention to refer to them. Right?

Comment: @KeithBennett: Yes, there are namespaces for variables, whether that be local variables (lexically scoped to block, method, class, module, and script bodies), instance variables (dynamically scoped to objects), class variables (dynamically scoped to class hierarchies including their instances), global variables (global scope), thread-local pseudo-globals like `$!`, method-local pseudo-globals like `$1`, and of course constants (mixed lexical and dynamic scoping, first looked up lexically "outwards" by nesting, then dynamically "upwards" by inheritance). But! This has nothing to do with …

Comment: … classes or modules, this applies regardless of what object the variable in question references. That's what I am getting at. Modules or classes are involved in constant lookup, because lookup is outwards by nested module/class body, and then upwards by ancestry (inheritance or mixin), but that is independent of what the constant references.

Answer (score 0):

@JörgWMittag answered my question in the comments (if you want to throw this into an answer I'll accept it):

```
module User
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

both resolve to the same constant in Ruby (`User`) and thus collide, whereas:

```
module User
  class AsActive < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

and

```
class ::User::AsActive < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

resolves to different Ruby constant (`User::AsActive` vs `User`).  Modules and classes use the same constant namespace (may not be best word to describe it, but it makes sense to me).

Comment: The error you are getting comes from telling Ruby that `User` is a module by saying `module User`, which it is not. In the second case, you are only applying the `::` operator to it, which works with all objects, so it is irrelevant what `User` is and that it is a class and not a module.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way, at least in Rails 6, to do this in separate files is:

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

# models/user/as_invitation.rb
class User
   class AsInvitation < User
   # ...
   end
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :users
namespace :user do
  resources :as_invitations
end

# controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplictionController
end

# controllers/user/as_invitations_controller.rb
class User::AsInvitationsController < UsersController
end
```